# Redux Toolkit - Best way to capture data from API in our redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have this question in my mind from past couple of days. What is the best way to capture data from an API in our redux store. I am using redux toolkit.

For e.g below is the code -

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(authUser.pending, state => {
        state.loading = 'pending';
      })
      .addCase(authUser.fulfilled, (state: LoginState, action: PayloadAction<Data>) => {
        state.loading = 'succeeded';
        state.entities.push(action.payload);
      })
  },
});
```

Like I have created an array, `entities` and pushed all the data inside it. And if I have to access this data inside my react components, it looks like this -

`const role = useSelector((state: RootState) => state?.user?.entities[0]?.roles[0])`

Is it fine or is there a better way of doing it. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, there is a better way of doing it. Your current approach is not scalable. Solution to your issue is create selector(`*.selectors.ts`) files.

For your above code example, create selector file as:
`user.selectors.ts`:

```
import { createSelector } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const selectAllUsers = (state) => state.entities;

const selectUserById = (userId) =>
  createSelector(selectAllUsers, (state) =>
    state.find((user) => user.id === userId)
  );
```

To use the same in your component files:

```
const allUsers = useSelector(selectAllUsers); // all users
const selctedUser = useSelector(selectUserById(9)); // user by id
```

Hope that answers your question.

Some useful link:

1. [createSelector](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSelector)
2. [idiomatic-redux-using-reselect-selectors](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/12/idiomatic-redux-using-reselect-selectors/)
3. [redux-reducers-selectors](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-reducers-selectors.md)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, i have used selectors now in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

All of this is covered in the [official Redux Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).

This specific question is covered in [chapter 6](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-6-performance-normalization) - you could do this with an `entityAdapter`, which would give you helpers to manage that `entities` collection and would also auto-create selectors for your.
But generally, I would recommend you read the whole thing - you are probably missing out on other features too if you ask this question.